# Handling "ducking" audioFocusChange with headphones

Tags: android, notifications, media-player

When Android receives an SMS the notification sends an AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK focus Change. I handle this by cutting the volume of the media player by 50%.

E.g.

```
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
      switch (focusChange) {
        // E.g. SMS
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK :
          playerDuck(true);
          break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN :
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT :
          playerDuck(false);
          playerResume();
          break;
      }
  }

  public synchronized void playerDuck(boolean duck) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      // Reduce the volume by half when ducking - otherwise play at full volume.
      mediaPlayer.setVolume(duck ? 0.5f : 1.0f, duck ? 0.5f : 1.0f);
    }
  }
```

This works fine when listening to the mediaplayer through the device's speaker but if you plug the headphones in then, instead of reducing the volume temporarily, the mediaplayer is muted whilst the notification plays.

How should I be handling the change in audio focus differently when the headphones are plugged in?

Comment: Question: Have you checked that you are getting the AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK ? I am logging and I see a AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT instead.